# How can I build a "cycle" helper for Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, cycle, helper

Basically, I want to add [this helper](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#cycle) to Razor. What I tried:

```
public static class Html
{
    static Dictionary<string[], int> _cycles;

    static Html()
    {
        _cycles = new Dictionary<string[], int>();
    }

    public static string Cycle(this HtmlHelper helper, string[] options)
    {
        if (!_cycles.ContainsKey(options)) _cycles.Add(options, 0);
        int index = _cycles[options];
        _cycles[options] = (options.Length + 1) % options.Length;
        return options[index];
    }
```

Usage:

```
<tr class="@Html.Cycle(new[]{"even","odd"})">
```

But it just says "even" for every row... not sure why. I'm not sure when this class gets instantiated.....is it once per request, once per server run...or what? Regardless...how would I fix this so that it gives the intended alternation?

---

### Attempt #2

```
public static class Html
{
    public static string Cycle(this HtmlHelper helper, params string[] options)
    {
        if(!helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items.Contains("cycles"))
            helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items["cycles"] = new Dictionary<string[],int>(new ArrayComparer<string>());
        var dict = (Dictionary<string[], int>)helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items["cycles"];
        if (!dict.ContainsKey(options)) dict.Add(options, 0);
        int index = dict[options];
        dict[options] = (index + 1) % options.Length;
        return options[index];
    }
}

class ArrayComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T[]>
{
    public bool Equals(T[] x, T[] y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (x == null || y == null) return false;
        if (x.Length != y.Length) return false;
        for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; ++i)
            if (!x[i].Equals(y[i])) return false;
        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T[] obj)
    {
        return obj.Length > 0 ? obj[0].GetHashCode() : 0;
    }
}
```

Any problem with this?

Comment: Your code will fail horribly with multiple threads.  Use `helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items`.

Comment: Just a small recommendation: use a `params` array.  `public static string Cycle(this HtmlHelper helper, params string[] options)`  This will let you call the function without the `new[]{...}` part.  Instead, you would just use `@Html.Cycle("even", "odd")`

Comment: @JohnGietzen: Right! Didn't think to use params. That's much nicer.

Comment: @SLaks: Yeah.... I thought there might be threading issues, but I didn't know how to approach this problem.

Comment: On your updated version:  I would clone the array before using it as a key for the dictionary (since this prevents weird behavior if someone were to modify the array).   Next, I would recommend using `Dictionary.TryGetValue`, rather than `Dictionary.ContainsKey`, since it allows the check to happen only once.  Other than that, this seems like it would work pretty well.

Comment: @JohnGietzen: But IDictionary doesn't have a TryGetValue? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.aspx). How would they modify `options` between when the function starts and when it exits?

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is failing, is because you are using a brand new array as the key to the dictionary every time.

I would recommend just including an extra parameter to be used as a dictonary key.

And *for god's sake*, please use a private storage area. (Rather than a `static` member, which will blow up when multiple threads hit the page.)

Comment: Can you elaborate on that last paragraph? I'm not sure where I should store this data, and how to get it to play nicely with multiple threads. Also, adding another parameter kind of defeats the nice simplicity of this helper. I'll add my own equality evaluator if I have to.

Comment: Well, @SLaks has a decent solution in his answer, using the `HttpContext` to store the index.

Comment: @JohnGrietzen: Now he does :) I think you posted this before he answered.

Answer (score 1):

Every call to your `Cycle` method passes a new `options` array, adding a new key to the dictionary.

Comment: Right! I was thinking they'd by equal via reference for some reason, but now that I think about it, that doesn't make any sense if it's a new object every time.

Answer (score 1):

To fix both this and the threading issue, you can use the strings themselves as keys in the HttpContext:

```
string key = "Cycle-"+String.Join("|", options);

if (!html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items.Contains(key))
     html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items.Add(key, 0);
int index = html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[key];
html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[key] = (index + 1) % options.Length;
return options[index];
```

Note that this will share cycles across child actions and sections.

Comment: I don't see where you've used `key`. Is that supposed I assume that's supposed to be used in place of `[options]` as the index? The thing I don't like about this approach is that `{"A","B","C"}` and `{"A","B|C"}` will compare equal.

Comment: @Mark: Correct; fixed.  You can choose a delimiter that you know will never appear in the options.  (eg, the complete text of Moby Dick)

Comment: `Items.ContainsKey` doesn't exist either. That confused me for awhile, since it's an `IDictionary`. But apparently it's not the generic IDictionary, just the other, non-generic one which only has `Contains`. According to the doc though, that looks for a key; i.e., it behaves like `ContainsKey`. Still not fond of choosing a 'rare' delimiter... we've got a lot of code at work that depends on stuff like that, "oh that'll never happen! No one will ever enter that!" and sooner or later, it always bites us in the ass. Especially when other options are available.

Comment: Also, this was my bad, but `(options.Length + 1)` is an error. That'll always evaluate to the same number; should be `index+1`.

Comment: You're right that using a delimiter is not a good idea; this is just the simplest option.  Using your own dictionary is much more robust.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out I could do this with an `@function` as well...then I don't need to add the namespace to `Web.config`.

```
@using MvcApplication4.Helpers @* for ArrayComparer *@

@functions {
    public static string Cycle(params string[] options)
    {
        if (!HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains("Html.Cycle"))
            HttpContext.Current.Items["Html.Cycle"] = new Dictionary<string[], int>(new ArrayComparer<string>());
        var dict = (Dictionary<string[], int>)HttpContext.Current.Items["Html.Cycle"];
        if (!dict.ContainsKey(options)) dict.Add(options, 0);
        int index = dict[options];
        dict[options] = (index + 1) % options.Length;
        return options[index];
    }
}
```

Could also do it with an `@helper` but I don't think it would be as clean.